# How to print $ in argument

Tags: bash

Unable to print same argument of $1

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^((-{1,2})([Hh]$|[Hh][Ee][Ll][Pp])|)$ ]]; then
            display_help; exit 1
    else
            while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
            opt="$1"
            shift;
            current_arg="$1"
            case "$opt" in
                    "run_command"   ) RUN_COMMAND="$1"; shift;;
                    "cmd1"          ) CMD1="$1"; shift;;
                    *                   ) echo "ERROR: Invalid option: \""$opt"\"" >&2
                          exit 1;;
            esac
            done
    fi

    if [[ "$RUN_COMMAND" == "Custom" ]];then
            export command1=`echo $CMD1`
            echo $command1
    else
            echo "Invalid arguments"
    fi
```

Result output

```
  ./test_non.sh run_command Custom cmd1 "date|awk '{print \\$1}'"
    date|awk '{print \}'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us the simplest possible version of your script that reproduces the error. We need something we can copy and run on our own machines.

Comment: How are you setting `$opt`, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
./script run_command Custom cmd1 "date|awk '{print \\$1}'"
```

Why? I don't really know the reason of that double `\`, but probably it need to escape the special character `$` AND the argument number too (one `\` for `$` and `1`)

Here is some results :

- good one :

  ```
  damadam@Pc:~$ export command1=`echo "date|awk '{print \\$1}'"`
  damadam@Pc:~$ echo $command1
  date|awk '{print $1}'
  ```
- tests :

  ```
  damadam@Pc:~$ export command1=`echo "date|awk '{print \$\1}'"`
  damadam@Pc:~$ echo $command1
  date|awk '{print $\1}'

  damadam@Pc:~$ export command1=`echo "date|awk '{print $\1}'"`
  damadam@Pc:~$ echo $command1
  date|awk '{print $\1}'
  ```
- OP test :

  ```
  damadam@Pc:~$ export command1=`echo "date|awk '{print \$1}'"`
  damadam@Pc:~$ echo $command1
  date|awk '{print }'
  ```

---

Edit 1: with the sample script code given by OP (I named it `test.sh` to test it personnally), just need a single `\` to escape the `$1` argument

```
damadam@Pc:~$ ./test.sh run_command Custom cmd1 "date|awk '{print \$1}'"
date|awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: You only needed the two ```\\``` because you were using two levels: first, the process substitution (```var1=`echo var2` ```), which wasn't needed anyway since you could just do `var1=var2`. The process substitution runs in a separate subshell, so you needed one escape to pass the `$1` correctly to that. Then, the whole thing was in double quotes, so you needed the second escape so that `$1` wasn't expanded in the double quotes before even being passed to the first subshell.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when you run this:

```
./script run_command Custom cmd1 "date|awk '{print $1}'"
```

Because your command is in double quotes, that means it will be expanded by the shell (bash) *before* calling your script. You can always test these things using `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ ./script run_command Custom cmd1 "date|awk '{print $1}'"
+ ./script run_command Custom cmd1 'date|awk '\''{print $1}'\'''
date|awk '{print $1}'
```

The line starting with `+` shows you the command actually run. As you can see, the `$1` has disappeared because `$` indicates a shell variable and, since you have everything in double quotes, that is passed to the shell which tries to expand it. Since `$1` isn't set, it expands to nothing. Compare it to what happens if you use a variable that is set:

```
$ foo="bar"
$ ./script run_command Custom cmd1 "date|awk '{print $foo}'"
+ ./script run_command Custom cmd1 'date|awk '\''{print bar}'\'''
date|awk '{print bar}'
```

As you can see, the `$foo` in your awk command is expanded to `bar` *before* being passed to `./script`. So, you need to escape the `$1`:

```
$ ./script run_command Custom cmd1 "date|awk '{print \$1}'"
+ ./script run_command Custom cmd1 'date|awk '\''{print $1}'\'''
date|awk '{print $1}'
```

I also don't understand what this is supposed to be doing:

```
if [[ "$RUN_COMMAND" == "Custom" ]];then
  export command1=`echo $CMD1`
  echo $command1
else
```

You [don't need](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107853/22222) `export` at all, and you don't need to echo one variable to set it as the value of another. All you need there is:

```
if [[ "$RUN_COMMAND" == "Custom" ]];then
  command1=$CMD1
```

In fact, you don't need `$CMD1` at all. Just set `$command1` from the beginning. Here's a slightly improved version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## dummy function since you didn't include yours
display_help(){
  echo "help"
}

if [[ "$1" =~ ^((-{1,2})([Hh]$|[Hh][Ee][Ll][Pp])|)$ ]]; then
  display_help
  exit 1
else
  while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    opt="$1"
    shift;
    current_arg="$1"
    case "$opt" in
      "run_command")
        RUN_COMMAND="$1"
        shift
        ;;
      "cmd1")
        command1="$1"
        shift
        ;;
      *)
        echo "ERROR: Invalid option: '$opt'" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
  done
fi

if [[ "$RUN_COMMAND" == "Custom" ]];then
  echo "$command1"
else
  echo "Invalid arguments"
fi
```